# How can a small MTU cause a Linux kernel crash?

Tags: linux, kernel, crash

`man 7 netdevice` states:

> SIOCGIFMTU, SIOCSIFMTU
>
> Get or set the MTU (Maximum Transfer Unit) of a device using ifr_mtu.  Setting the MTU is a privileged operation. **Setting the MTU to too small values may cause kernel crashes.**

I don't see any connection between MTU and a kernel crash. Under what circumstances could a small MTU value lead to a kernel crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small MTU leads to more packets.
Many more packets? Too much work for the kernel, hence a crash/. 
Is this intellectual curiosity at work, or do you have a problem which involves this?